# If input value includes values from an array as well as extra characters

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, include

I'm attempting to create a postcode search that includes an error message if an invalid postcode is entered.

I have identified the postcodes that are to be valid in an array and declared a statement that if the input value includes any of these values the error message will not display. However as I have declared only the first letters of the postcode, when a complete postcode is entered that includes additional characters as well as a value from the array, the error message is displayed.

How can I make it so that if the first letters of the input value equal an array value along with additional characters the message remains off?

Is the statement `if(include())` not the way to go?

[JSFiddle of what I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/xbxygguz/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are testing equality (in other words an exact match) in your include function. Try updating it to see if each possible postcode prefix (item in arr) starts your string:

```
function include(arr, obj) {

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (obj.indexOf(arr[i]) === 0) return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I know you are just debugging right now, though I'd suggest pulling the common code in the change and click event handlers into its own function, so you don't have to copy and paste (and fix bugs twice!)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Phil. That's exactly what I was looking for.